# How to wrap plain text honoring existing text indent?

Tags: indentation, formatting

With at least these settings:

```
expandtab
textwidth=79
sw=4
ts=4
fo=tcq
```

If I have a long line of text that starts with a `*` (like a C/javadoc comment) it will honor the current indent level when I `gqq`, albeit formatting it like a code comment, e.g.:

```
* I'm convinced of this: Good done anywhere is good done everywhere...
```

=>

```
* I'm convinced of this: Good done anywhere is good done
* everywhere. For a change, start by speaking to people
* rather than walking by them like they're stones that
* don't matter. As long as you're breathing, it's never too
* late to do some good.
```

However, if I remove the leading `*`, it just wraps flush with the left:

```
    I'm convinced of this: Good done anywhere is good done
everywhere. For a change, start by speaking to people rather than walking by
them like they're stones that don't matter. As long as you're breathing, it's
never too late to do some good.
```

I'm just doing plain text prose in a .txt.  How can I make it look like the following, ideally without any fancy leading char?

```
I'm convinced of this: Good done anywhere is good done
everywhere. For a change, start by speaking to people rather
than walking by them like they're stones that don't matter.
As long as you're breathing, it's never too late to do some
good.
```

I was able to do this by manually deleting all leading whitespace, passing the line through `:!fmt -w60`, and then block inserting 20 spaces; but that involves a lot of math and typing, a cumbersome external command, and is not platform independent (wouldn't work in windows, for instance).

Sample Text is a quote from Maya Angelou.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like if you have `autoindent` set, then `gqq` honors the indentation of the line you’re on.

Here is my setup:

```
    ~ ω  vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Feb 10 2016 14:15:10)
MacOS X (unix) version
Included patches: 1-1257
Compiled by Homebrew
...
```

Start Vim without any initialization files:

```
vim -u NONE
```

Then:

- paste in a long line and giving it any indent
- `:set autoindent`
- `gqq`

Give it a try! 8-)